# Why is tf2::doTransform eating CPU but pcl_ros::TransformPointCloud not?

Tags: tf2, ros-noetic, perception-pcl

I want to perform a coordinate frame transformation and found recently [`tf2_sensor_msgs`](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/bfcd60628a75519b9f59864c12e742f0e24184d6/tf2_sensor_msgs/include/tf2_sensor_msgs/tf2_sensor_msgs.h) as a way to apply the transformation without the need to convert `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` to `pcl::PointCloud<T>` type and then use `pcl_ros::TransformPointCloud`. However, it performed really bad.

That's the way that I am using:

```
void TransformFilter::operator()(sensor_msgs::PointCloud2& pc)
{
  geometry_msgs::TransformStamped tf;
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 pcl_output;
  try
  {
    tf = tf_buffer_.lookupTransform(target_frame_, pc.header.frame_id, pc.header.stamp, timeout_);
  }
  catch (tf2::TransformException& ex)
  {
    ROS_WARN_STREAM("TransformFilter: " << ex.what());
    return;
  }

  tf2::doTransform(pc, pcl_output, tf);
  pc = std::move(pcl_output);
  return;
}
```

and this approach requires `95%` of my CPU when I run the robot

while the `PCL` approach would be:

```
template <class PointCloudStruct>
  void pclOperator(pcl::PointCloud<PointCloudStruct>& pc)
  {
    geometry_msgs::TransformStamped tf;
    try
    {
      tf = tf_buffer_.lookupTransform(target_frame_, pc.header.frame_id, pcl_conversions::fromPCL(pc.header.stamp),
                                      timeout_);
    }
    catch (tf2::TransformException& ex)
    {
      ROS_WARN_STREAM("TransformFilter: " << ex.what());
      return;
    }

    pcl_ros::transformPointCloud(pc, pc, tf.transform);
    pc.header.frame_id = tf.header.frame_id;
  }
```

and that uses `35%` of my CPU

I initially tried using `tf2::doTransform(pc, pc, tf);`, but also had issues with that.

Does anyone knows why/where is the issue here? I thought the `doTransform` would get me lower than `35%` of CPU usage as I skip the convertion.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Can you please clarify what you mean by "bad," "worse," "issue," or other ambiguous terms in your question?  Please modify your question and elaborate them precisely.